# How to identify which errors are thrown by a method

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

Simple question, not yet answered in previous threads - *please read carefully the answers to those threads before marking this as duplicate, question might be duplicated but the answers are not satisfying yet* - how to identify which errors are thrown by a method in order to specify that in catch clauses?

As an example, please have a look to the code below. It works, but I prefer to to have a single level of do - and multiple catches at the same nested level, not nested do(s).

To achieve that I need to know which ErrorType String.init(contentsOf:encoding:) and String.write(to:atomically:encoding:) are thrown and apparently there is no way to figure out that, neither from documentation, nor from source code.

Am I missing something here?

```
    do {
            var contents =  try String(contentsOf: indexFileUrl, encoding: .utf8)
            let jsonText = String(describing: SmartGamesManager.shared.jsonText)
            contents = contents.replacingOccurrences(of: text, with: jsonText)
            // write to file
            do {
                try contents.write(to: indexFileUrl, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            }
            catch  {
                print("could not write file index.html")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("could not retrieve content of index.html")
        }
```

Comment: You can only catch certain error types, you cannot determine which of your several throwable functions threw an error if several methods can throw the same error. One feasible solution for this is to rethrow a custom error, but even then you'd need nested do-catch blocks.

Comment: What about using optional try?  IE: `if let blah = try? Something() {}` https://pastebin.com/KRi6eA2k

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much you can do about this without pulling your hair out. The solution Dávid provides is the one I personally use; I create my own `enum` type that conforms to `Error` and `CustomStringConvertible` that "forwards" the underlaying `Error`s.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I find incredible this can not be handled as in Java exceptions...not looking for a workaround here.

Comment: You could do `var contents: String; do { contents = try String(contentsOf: indexFileUrl, encoding: .utf8) } catch { print("could not retrieve content of index.html"); return } let jsonText = ...`. Although that being said, I don't quite see what you're trying to achieve by separating the `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'catch'-block is a constant called 'error' which contains the error that was thrown by the Method. You can call its attribute 'localizedDescription' to get Information about the error, or you could also cast it as a NSError and use its variety of attributes to get any Information that were thrown by the Method

For example:

```
      do {
                var contents =  try String(contentsOf: indexFileUrl,
encoding: .utf8)
                let jsonText = String(describing: SmartGamesManager.shared.jsonText)
                contents = contents.replacingOccurrences(of: text, with: jsonText)

                do {
                    try contents.write(to: indexFileUrl, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                }
                catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            catch let nserr as NSError {
                print(nserr.description) // one of many attributes
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @Juliannvro but that's not at all what I am looking for here, I want to know which kind of errors can be thrown by the method, at compile time in order to handle them, not to read about them at runtime.